# Eclipse Quick Fix or menu option for importing different Java class?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, autocomplete

I have written a project that includes a `Character` class. In this project, in a different package, I have another class that's trying to use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHARACTERS; i++) {
    Character c = new Character(10);
}
```

The problem is that Eclipse is automatically trying to use `java.lang.Character`:

[image]

What I would *like* to do, is find a way either via the contextual menu, keyboard shortcut, Quick Fix menu, etc. to have Eclipse provide me with alternate imports.

The issue is obviously that the class is part of the standard API, otherwise it would certainly ask me which `Character` class to import. Normally if you've imported the wrong one accidentally, you can just delete it from your `import` block at the top, and use Quick Fix to pick the right one.

But how, in this case, can I **easily tell Eclipse I want to use a different class**, without having to manually type the import into the top? I have a number of classes that will be named similarly to the `java.lang` classes, so I'm looking for a time-saving solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will give you an option to select the required package.

Just place the cursor at end like Character^ and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

where `^` show your cursor position. For example

`Date` class is present in `java.util` as well as `java.sql`, so when you will type

Date^ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, it will pop-up with all the packages where `Date` class is present and you can choose your desired import from there.

Another way, Just delete all the auto imports & press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to organize imports. Eclipse will prompt you for all the place wherever there is any ambiguity in identifying the right `package`.

Comment: That's pretty close - it requires quite a few steps though, at least on Kepler. I have to `Ctrl+Space` for the constructor, then Quick Fix for the variable type (which is still `java.lang.Character`) then `Command+Shift+M` on the variable type to import the class rather than using the fully-qualified name, then do the same on the constructor.